# Ensuring compatibility between members with lower-bounded generics

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I'm building a generic `AssemblyLine` class that takes physical objects, measures them, puts them in cardboard boxes, and gift-wraps them. I want users to be able to be able to provide their own object measurement strategies (maybe some care about total volume and some just care about the longest dimension of the object) and also their own box selection strategies (since users will know best which cardboard boxes they want to use).

It would be great if the `AssemblyLine` could accept measurement strategies and box selection strategies that operate on superclasses of the physical object. After all, if a user has a measurement strategy that works for all kinds of `Dessert`, we ought to let them use that same strategy in both their `AssemblyLine<Cake>` and `AssemblyLine<Pie>`, right?

So let's start with the measurement strategy:

```
public interface PhysicalObjectMeasurementStrategy<T> {
    Measurement measureObject(T object);
}
```

Simple enough, and I think uncontroversial. Next, we want to define an interface for the box selection strategy. This may be my first mistake, but let's roll with it for now:

```
public interface CardboardBoxSelectionStrategy<T> {
    CardboardBoxSize chooseCardboardSizeForObject(T object, PhysicalObjectMeasurementStrategy<? super T> measurementStrategy);
}
```

The idea is that I'd like to be able to choose a box for anything we can measure. If we have a box selection strategy for pies and a measurement strategy that can handle any dessert, it'd be nice to be able to use the dessert measurement strategy in multiple places.

Now, to bring it all together into an assembly line:

```
public class AssemblyLine<T> {
    private final PhysicalObjectMeasurementStrategy<? super T> measurementStrategy;
    private final CardboardBoxSelectionStrategy<? super T> boxSelectionStrategy;

    // ...
    public void giftWrapObject(final T physicalObject) {
        // Here's where things fall apart:
        boxSelectionStrategy.chooseCardboardSizeForObject(physicalObject, this.measurementStrategy);

        // ...
    }
}
```

The problem, as near as I can tell (and this may be completely wrong!), is that we don't have any way to guarantee that both `measurementStrategy` and `boxSelectionStrategy` are referring to the same superclass of `T`, and may in fact be referring to unrelated superclasses (or interfaces). For example, we could have a situation where we have:

- `PhysicalObjectMeasurementStrategy<Cylindrical>`
- `CardboardBoxSelectionStrategy<Edible>`
- `AssemblyLine<Cake>`

Both strategies would be appropriate for the assembly line, but because not all `Cylindrical` objects are `Edible` (or vice versa), it doesn't make sense to pass the measurement strategy to the box selection strategy.

So, to the point: is there a good way to make sure we're talking about the same—or at least compatible—superclasses when declaring or constructing the `AssemblyLine`? If not, is there another good way to approach this problem (does this problem have a name?), or do I need to rethink the design and possibly use less flexible components in the assembly line?

Thanks kindly!

Comment: When you receive the measurement stategy as `MeasurementStrategy<? super T> measurement`, then you can't call the `measureObject` method at all (because it expects an *unknown* supertype of T). I think this is the root cause of the problem. Did you consider this? How do you want to solve this? Is this what the question is actually about? (It's not related to the `AssemblyLine` class, in this regard. There are reasons of *why* this is not possible, that could be elaborated in a possible answer, I just want to be sure that the answer is appropriate for the question....)

Comment: @Marco13 You can call `measureObject` with an object of type `T` (or null).

Comment: @Alex `null` does not make sense here, and an object of type `T` is simply not available (unless one "pins" the objects to this type, similar to your first proposed solution - but I'm not sure whether this is what the asker wants to achieve...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use separate type parameters for the measurement and box selection strategies that are compatible:

```
class AssemblyLine<M, B extends M> {
    private final PhysicalObjectMeasurementStrategy<M> measurementStrategy;
    private final CardboardBoxSelectionStrategy<B> boxSelectionStrategy;

    public void giftWrapObject(B physicalObject) {...
```

Another way might be to allow any measurement strategy that can measure the object to be passed to the box selection strategy:

```
<R extends T> CardboardBoxSize chooseCardboardSizeForObject(R object, 
        PhysicalObjectMeasurementStrategy<? super R> measurementStrategy);
```

Or you could measure the object first then pass the measurment to the box selection stategy.

I don't know if there is a name for this problem.

Comment: I think the "any measurement strategy that can measure the object" approach might be right; let me think about it a bit before I accept, though!

Comment: This compiles, but I'm not 100% sure I understand why. How does the `<R extends T>` strategy solve the edible/cylindrical problem above? Couldn't I still have mismatched strategies in the `AssemblyLine`? Is the idea that two `<? super T>` strategies may not work together in the general case, but because we've specified `AssemblyLine<Cake>`, we know they will in this specific case?

Comment: @JonChambers Yes, they can still be mismatched, and we know that the measurement strategy can measure the object, just not that it can measure an object with the type of the type parameter from the box selection strategy. So the `R` is necessary to capture the type that the measurement strategy can measure (the `T` from `AssemblyLine`).

Comment: If you don't want them to be mismatched the first way will prevent that.